# Can I change attributes from a symbol (function) in another c-File?

Tags: c, gcc, weak-references, pragma

I try to keep this as simple as I can (even tho I have a relating question running, but this is supposed to be more general.

When I declare a function `extern void foo(void)` with a prototype and call it in the same C-File, can I give it the attribute `weak` in another C-File?

The reason is this: Whether the `extern` function `foo()` is implemented depends on some build options and may OR may not be added to the binary. If it is not, I get (obviously) an error `undefined reference`. This is why I want to declare it weak (with `__attribute__((weak))` from GCC or with `#pragma weak`. For some reason (to long to explain here) I want to do this in a seperate C-File, without adding the `#pragma`/`attribute` to the original declaration? - Is there anyway to do this? If I just add `#pragma weak foo` to anothr C-File it won't work. ( I am using GCC 4.8.1 )

//edit: as requested some code:
Note: The implementation of `foo` is **not** linked to the project

Function.c

```
extern void foo(void);
// #pragma weak foo    <-- If I add it here, it links without problems

void bar(void)
{
     foo();
}
```

WeakDeclaration.c

```
#pragma weak foo <-- If I add it here, I get undefined reference error
```

**//edit2:**

Ok I gonna try so specify my question a bit more - is there any way to make the symbol `foo` globally visible to the linker with the attribute `weak` from within another C-File (`WeakDeclaration.c`)

Comment: Your explanation is confusing, please show some code. Also define what you mean by *"it won't work"*.

Comment: Do you call or otherwise reference the function? If so, I don't understand at all how you can expect to sometimes build without it ...

Answer (score 1):

You can switch the pragma using an included header and macro commands:

Function.c:

```
#include "weak.h"
...
extern void foo(void);
#ifdef TURN_ON_WEAK
#pragma weak foo
#endif
```

weak.h:

```
#ifndef MY_WEAK_H
#define MY_WEAK_H

#define TURN_ON_WEAK

#endif
```

Comment: Yeah thats the solution I was thinking about, but I was actually wondering if there is a way to do so, without putting an ´#ifdef´ in every file I want to declare a function weak.

Comment: is it possible to use the pragma more than once? If yes, you could just put both the extern declaration and pragma into one header file. And if you want to selectively disable the pragma in some file (the file with function body?) you could put `#define TURN_OFF_WEAK` before including the file and have the ifdef condition inside of your include file

Comment: That would be a solution - but what I am searching for is more like a way to make the `weak` declaration completely independent in another file (see edit2 on my question)